# Get First Next element with classname Plain Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to Get First Child with classname Plain Javascript.

I am trying to write my own form validation and  trying the error message i appended and remove it. As well as dont append if error message is already there.

If you help me with just the first part getting child with class name that whould be great.

```
    function display_error(selector, message) {
    selector.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', "<h1 class='js-error' >" + message + "</h1>");
}

function validateForm() {
    // Validate Name Field
    // Check if name has les than 3
    var elem = document.getElementById("name")
    if (elem.value.length < 3) {
        display_error(elem, "Less than 3")
        return false;
    } else {
        // here is the error
        error_label = elem.querySelector('.js-error');
        error_label.textContent = "more than 3"

        }

}
```

here is a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/efh941cc/3/

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Comment: When you use `afterend`, the new element isn't a child, it's the next element.

Comment: What class name are you trying to get?

Comment: Well i am trying to get the next element and remove it on the else stament. thankyou for telling me its the next not child

Comment: I think you want `elem.nextElementSibling`. Then test if it has `class="js-error"`

Comment: i think ur right barmar thankyou now to google how test for that

Answer (score 3):

The beautiful thing about **[`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)** is that you can use CSS selectors rather than the, often clunky, DOM API.

CSS provides a very simple selector called **[`first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)** which does exactly what you need.

```js
// Find the first element that uses the .test class that is a child of another element.
var firstTest = document.querySelector(".test:first-child");

// Now that you've scanned and found the element and stored a reference to it
// in a variable, you can access any aspect of the element.
console.log(firstTest.textContent);

firstTest.innerHTML = "<span>Now, I have completely different content than before!</span>";

// Now, we can get a reference to other elements that are relative to the last 
// one we found.
var firstTestError = document.querySelector(".test:first-child + .error");

firstTestError.style.backgroundColor = "aqua";
firstTestError.innerHTML = "<span>Required</span>";
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="test">one</span><span class="error"></span>
  <div class="test">two</div>
  <div class="test">three</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: this is great thankyou but how do i find the using  var elem so i can use var elem.id and just put in the selector

Comment: Just cache the resulting element. I'll update the answer.

Comment: this is what i got       error_label = document.querySelector("#" + elem.id +:".error-js")

Comment: @HollyJohnson I don't follow you. You don't need to query by the `id` if you are looking for the element based on the first child to use the `.test` class.

Comment: Its because i was not good at explain what i wanted. I am trying to find the next element and that has a certain class. this has helped me. thankyouf

Comment: @HollyJohnson What is the class of the next element? Instead of using JavaScript to write the entire error element next to the first element. Just create the element ahead of time and then you just need to query for it and populate it.

Answer (score 2):

In modern JavaScript, to get the first child with a class name, you can use the following:

```
document.querySelector('element.class:first-child')
```

Here, you supply the *actual* element, and the *actual* class name.

`document.querySelector` is available in all modern browsers, and will take any string which matches a CSS selector. It even works in IE8, though the `:first-child` pseudo class is not available there.

Answer (score -2):

const GetFirstChild = document.querySelector(' .PlainJavascript');

Comment: Please format your code. Also this doesn't work: 1) variable names can't have spaces 2) you didn't use dot prefix to a class name 3) class names can't have spaces